# How to dynamically insert data into "react-minimal-pie-chart"

Tags: reactjs, pie-chart

I am using  [react-minimal-pie-chart](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-minimal-pie-chart) to show a pie chart on my website. I can easily show the pie chart with a static value. But i want to insert data  dynamically into the pie chart from my json data. I call the rest api from the backend, and get the json value. Here is my code for the pie chart:

```
import ReactMinimalPieChart from 'react-minimal-pie-chart';

    <ReactMinimalPieChart

    data={[
    {
    title: 'One',
    value: 100,
    color: '#E38627'
    },
    {
    title: 'Two',
    value: 150,
    color: '#C13C37'
    },
    {
    title: 'Three',
    value: 10,
    color: '#6A2135'
    }
    ]}
    lineWidth={15}
    style={{height: '170px'}}
    />
```

My rest api for json value:

```
<div>
     {
     this.state.leadSourceList.map((lead, key) =>
        {lead.lead_source}
        {lead.count}
    )}
</div>
```

getting json values

```
 {count: 3, lead_source: "jobaer"} 
 {count: 2, lead_source: "web"} 
 {count: 1, lead_source: "sourav"} 
 {count: 2, lead_source: "Hop Freeman"}
```

I want to insert this data into the pie chart. I searched google, but I didn't get any convenient answer. Any help regarding this would be appreciated or if there is any alternative way to insert a value into pie chart or using alternative pie chart, please inform me.

[image: this circle comes, but color is same for all]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two simple steps.

First, map over `this.state.leadSourceList` so that each item is converted to the following format:

`{ title: 'lead_source', value: count, color: '{foo_color}'}`

like so:

```
const pieData = this.state.leadSourceList.map((lead, key) => {
    return { 'title': lead.lead_source, 'value': lead.count, 'color': '{foo_color}'};
})
```

Then, create your chart as follows:

```
<ReactMinimalPieChart data={pieData}/>
```

Comment: After mapping **this.state.leadSourceList** i am getting string value  like **3 jobaer** **2 web**. how to get value like that format?

Comment: @jobaer sourav - please upvote and "accept" this answer if you find it helpful :)

Comment: Yes Brother, it comes. but  it's not get the color. How to set different color for different pie?

Comment: Perhaps initialize an array of strings of desired colors, and as you are iterating over the JSON data, assign each object a different color.

Comment: see my updated question for seeing the pie chart i get. i will initialize an array but how to assign them for different values? bcz i am mapping **this.state.leadSourceList.map** this, how to set different color

Comment: How to set color dynamically brother?